# Is Number of tags attached to a view in Android limited?

Tags: android

Do we have any limit to add number of tags to a view using method `void setTag (int key, Object tag)` or we can add unlimited tags to a view.

Comment: Its unlimited, system manages it when you are not interacting with a view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add any amount of tags with different keys with the `setTag(int key, Object tag)` method, and you can add one tag with the `setTag(Object tag)` method. The former are stored in a `SparseArray<Object>` inside `View`, the latter is just a simple `Object` that you're getting and setting.

Keep this in mind about the keys:

> The specified key should be an id declared in the resources of the
>   application to ensure it is unique (see the ID resource type). Keys
>   identified as belonging to the Android framework or not associated
>   with any package will cause an IllegalArgumentException to be thrown.

[Source](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag(int,%20java.lang.Object))